# Change Windows 10 screen refresh rate. 59 if 60, 60 if 59

Tags: powershell, batch-file

How can I change the Windows Display settings refresh rate from 59 to 60?

I cannot find anything on how to accomplish this through PowerShell or a Batch script.
I will only find anything on the screen resolution.

What I am trying to accomplish is:

```
If 60 hz then set 59 hz
        else (set 60 hz)
```

But it doesn't seem to have any native cmdlets for it?

I have only tried to search for any cmdlet or other wmi solutions, that could possibly do this, but have only found how to change the display resolution.

EDIT:

A combination with what mhu posted and the wmi I have managed to get a somewhat close to functioning solution.

```
$RefreshRate = Get-WmiObject -Class:Win32_videocontroller | Select-Object -ExpandProperty currentrefreshrate

if ($RefreshRate = 60){
    Set-ScreenResolution -Width 2560 -Height 1440 -Frequency 59
    }
else {
    Set-ScreenResolution -Width 2560 -Height 1440 -Frequency 60
    }
```

However this still doesn't make it swap between the two refreshrates.
Any idea, on how to just get the numbers from the WmiObject?

EDIT2:
So I added -ExpandProperty parameter to the Select-Object. It now outputs just 60 or 59. But it still doesn't swap between the two :(.

Comment: Literally, just one Google search returned this from the Super User forum: https://superuser.com/questions/1184815/is-a-way-to-quickly-set-screen-refresh-rate

Comment: Thanks for your input. However I have tried all these. And they each require an external software or module to function.
I am a bit more interrested in a more native way of doing it.

Comment: @Heine Kristensen `if 60 then 59` `if 59 then 60`. Why do you want this particular `else` statement?

Comment: @SNR I want the `else` statement, because if i do both I will always end out with the last.
E.g. `if 59 then 60` and then add `if 60 then 59` output will always change it to 60, no matter what.

Comment: @Heine Kristensen Ja, but why do you want this kind of logic? Sorry I've might not been clear the first time.

Comment: @SNR Ahh, yes. Ehm.. It is because I have an issue where everytime I undock and use the laptop, the picture becomes blurry. So when I switch from 59 hz to 60 hz, it becomes crystal clear, until next time. Then swapping between them changes it.
I'm not sure if the current thing will fix it tbh. Might try and attempt it.

Comment: @Heine Kristensen Does this help https://superuser.com/questions/1184815/is-a-way-to-quickly-set-screen-refresh-rate .Not sure for that reson I prefer to ask.

Comment: @SNR Well, I am currently using a combination of that, and the one that @mhu posted below.
However I am struggling to get plain value numbers from the `wmic PATH Win32_videocontroller get currentrefreshrate` so I can get it to work.
If I could get that pure integer, I'm almost certain that it will work.

Comment: Note: If there are multiple monitors, multiple `System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\Win32_VideoController` objects will be produced by `Get-WmiObject -Class:Win32_videocontroller`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on https://pastebin.com/QQkcveSM (removed resolution setting):

```
function Set-ScreenRefreshRate
{ 
    param ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
        [int] $Frequency
    ) 

    $pinvokeCode = @"         
        using System; 
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 

        namespace Display 
        { 
            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
            public struct DEVMODE1 
            { 
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)] 
                public string dmDeviceName; 
                public short dmSpecVersion; 
                public short dmDriverVersion; 
                public short dmSize; 
                public short dmDriverExtra; 
                public int dmFields; 

                public short dmOrientation; 
                public short dmPaperSize; 
                public short dmPaperLength; 
                public short dmPaperWidth; 

                public short dmScale; 
                public short dmCopies; 
                public short dmDefaultSource; 
                public short dmPrintQuality; 
                public short dmColor; 
                public short dmDuplex; 
                public short dmYResolution; 
                public short dmTTOption; 
                public short dmCollate; 
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)] 
                public string dmFormName; 
                public short dmLogPixels; 
                public short dmBitsPerPel; 
                public int dmPelsWidth; 
                public int dmPelsHeight; 

                public int dmDisplayFlags; 
                public int dmDisplayFrequency; 

                public int dmICMMethod; 
                public int dmICMIntent; 
                public int dmMediaType; 
                public int dmDitherType; 
                public int dmReserved1; 
                public int dmReserved2; 

                public int dmPanningWidth; 
                public int dmPanningHeight; 
            }; 

            class User_32 
            { 
                [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
                public static extern int EnumDisplaySettings(string deviceName, int modeNum, ref DEVMODE1 devMode); 
                [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
                public static extern int ChangeDisplaySettings(ref DEVMODE1 devMode, int flags); 

                public const int ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS = -1; 
                public const int CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY = 0x01; 
                public const int CDS_TEST = 0x02; 
                public const int DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL = 0; 
                public const int DISP_CHANGE_RESTART = 1; 
                public const int DISP_CHANGE_FAILED = -1; 
            } 

            public class PrimaryScreen  
            { 
                static public string ChangeRefreshRate(int frequency) 
                { 
                    DEVMODE1 dm = GetDevMode1(); 

                    if (0 != User_32.EnumDisplaySettings(null, User_32.ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, ref dm)) 
                    { 
                        dm.dmDisplayFrequency = frequency;

                        int iRet = User_32.ChangeDisplaySettings(ref dm, User_32.CDS_TEST); 

                        if (iRet == User_32.DISP_CHANGE_FAILED) 
                        { 
                            return "Unable to process your request. Sorry for this inconvenience."; 
                        } 
                        else 
                        { 
                            iRet = User_32.ChangeDisplaySettings(ref dm, User_32.CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY); 
                            switch (iRet) 
                            { 
                                case User_32.DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL: 
                                { 
                                    return "Success"; 
                                } 
                                case User_32.DISP_CHANGE_RESTART: 
                                { 
                                    return "You need to reboot for the change to happen.\n If you feel any problems after rebooting your machine\nThen try to change resolution in Safe Mode."; 
                                } 
                                default: 
                                { 
                                    return "Failed to change the resolution"; 
                                } 
                            } 
                        } 
                    } 
                    else 
                    { 
                        return "Failed to change the resolution."; 
                    } 
                } 

                private static DEVMODE1 GetDevMode1() 
                { 
                    DEVMODE1 dm = new DEVMODE1(); 
                    dm.dmDeviceName = new String(new char[32]); 
                    dm.dmFormName = new String(new char[32]); 
                    dm.dmSize = (short)Marshal.SizeOf(dm); 
                    return dm; 
                } 
            } 
        } 
"@ # don't indend this line

    Add-Type $pinvokeCode -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    [Display.PrimaryScreen]::ChangeRefreshRate($frequency) 
}

function Get-ScreenRefreshRate
{
    $frequency = Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_VideoController" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "CurrentRefreshRate"

    return $frequency
}
```

To call this function in your case:

```
$currentFrequency = Get-ScreenRefreshRate
$newFrequency     = if ($currentFrequency -eq 59) { 60 } else { 59 }

Set-ScreenRefreshRate -Frequency $newFrequency
```

Comment: Hmm.. I actually did try this one, however it did change the resolution and refresh rate. I just realized that maybe I can manage to combine the wmic function to get the refreshrate and make it a "1 button refresh rate changer".
Thank you.

Comment: Alright, so I managed to succeed 50% with this.
    $RefreshRate = wmic PATH Win32_videocontroller get currentrefreshrate
    if ($RefreshRate = 60){
    Set-ScreenResolution -Width 2560 -Height 1440 -Frequency 59}
    else {
       Set-ScreenResolution -Width 2560 -Height 1440 -Frequency 60} 
This changes it to 59 if it is on 60. But not the otherway around.
I'm a bit suspicious that it is my $RefreshRate variable that gives the extra "CurrentRefreshRate" output.

Comment: Updated the answer (bottom line: in your comment `=` should be `-eq`)

Comment: Oh wow. I did not know, you could do that if else statement in a single line.
Thank you very much, this worked 100% as intended.